# Methed works but I can't send result from methed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a problem with my code and I can't understand what am I wrong.
I connected with mongodb. There a four documents with fields - _id, num, str in it.
I taked "Hello World!" split into four parts and put it in four documents ("Hel","lo ", "Wor", "ld!"). And now I want to collect parts together.
This is my methed.

```
function f(hwUsers, num){
    let result = '';
        for(let n of num){
            hwUsers.aggregate([{"$match": {num: n}},{"$project":{str: 1, _id: 0}}])
            .then((hwu) => hwu.map(item => {
                result = result + item.str;
                console.log(result);
                return result;
                }))
            .catch((err) => {console.log(err);});
        }
    
    return result;   
}
```

It works in loop. I see it when I'm launching application but I can't send result from methed.

```
resStr = f(hwUsers, numbers);
```

resStr is empty when I call the methed.

Answer (score 0):

`hwUsers.aggregate` is an async function, so when you call `f`, it loops through very quickly and calls it in a loop, not waiting for the result.  This means that `result` is still `''` when it returns.

Try using `await` instead of `.then`.